# How do I setup my Ubuntu 18.04 server to allow for WebSockets?

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, websocket, ubuntu-18.04

I have an Ubuntu-18.04 server (which we will say has the hostname s1.hostname.com for the sake of ease) that was set up on DigitalOcean using these 2 tutorials (so you know what it have installed etc currently):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-18-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04

I have a number of website projects which use frequent AJAX requests which use a lot of the CPU. In looking for ways to optimize this I discovered WebSockets. When I tested various examples that used the I found online locally using XAMPP I managed to get them to work, however when I tried the same code on my server I kept getting a variety of errors which led to me realise that my server probably doesn't support WebSockets.

What I ideally want is for me to be able to use the JavaScript WebSocket to connect to s1.mydomain.com:port and be able to send/receive JSON information with the server this way.

Alternatively if an alternate server type/configuration would be better to achieve this I'm happy to move the websites/projects to s2.mydomain.com with a different setup. Or if there are any not-to-costly WebSocket hosts out there which I can pay for I'm happy to use them also.

Comment: Have you searched any for nodejs + websockets?  Should be a ton of tutorials out there.

Comment: PHP is interesting, but it's not the best platform for WebSockets (for historical reasons that have to do with it's CGI approach). node.js, Ruby, Python... hell, even C... are better options.